# IP address family identification

Tags: c, linux, ip, ip-address, kernel-module

I have a requirement of identifying IP address family of an IP of a packet (i.e IPv4 or IPv6). In have managed to capture packets utilizing `libnetfilter` and obtain the source and destination IP addresses. But now I need to identify the obtained IP addresses address family from the `kernel module` i am implementing.

The IP addresses are stored as follows,

```
struct iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);  

unsigned int src_ip = (unsigned int)ip_header->saddr;   
unsigned int dest_ip = (unsigned int)ip_header->daddr;
```

During my research I came up empty handed on how to perform this function, I only found on how to format and display it as a string using `%pI4` and `%pI6`. but not how to identify the IP address family programatically. (may be like the Linux kernel module equivalent to the function `IPAddress.AddressFamily`)

I would be really grateful if you experts could assist me in this issue which I was stuck in for quite a few days.

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**

With @alk 's suggestion, I would be really grateful if you experts would advice me in altering the above mentioned `unsigned int` variable declarations to support IPv6 also. :)

Comment: @alk thank you fort he reply sir. How should I modify this to support both IPv4 and IPv6 and identify the version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first 4 bit of what the pointer returned by `skb_network_header` points to gives you the version of the ip header and with this version of the packet.

Depending on this you need to tread the header differently.

```
void * p = (void *) skb_network_header(skb);
unsigned int protocol_version = (*((unsigned char *) p) & 0xf0) >> 4;

switch (protocol_version)
{
case 4:
  struct ip_hdr * pip4_hdr = p; 

  printk("src=%pI4\n", &pip4_hdr->saddr);
  printk("dst=%pI4\n", &pip4_hdr->daddr);

  break;

case 6;
  struct ip6_hdr * pip6_hdr = p;

  printk("src=%pI6\n", &pip6_hdr->ip6_src);
  printk("dst=%pI6\n", &pip6_hdr->ip6_dst);

  break;

default:
  printk("<unhandled protocol version: %u>\n", protocol_version);

  break;
}
```

*(untested)*

For reference: The structures of the [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_header#Fixed_header) and the [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header#Header) header.

Comment: Thank you fir this answer :) i will check and post back :)

Comment: Thanks again for the answer :) I know you have mentioned it as untested, I tried out the code, but it gives the `protocol_version` as 0 always. can i know whats happening over here - `void * p = (void *) skb_network_header(skb);
unsigned int protocol_version = ntohs(*(uint16_t*) p) & 0x000f;` ? Is this function the same as doing `struct iphdr *iph; unsigned int protocol_version = iph->version` ? You help is greatly appreciated sir :)

Comment: Try it with removing the conversion function `ntohs`. Perhaps the header data already is in host bytes order. If just doing `unsigned int protocol_version = *((uint16_t *) p); ` what do you get for `protocol_version`?

Comment: `ntohs(*(uint16_t*) p) & 0x000f;` treats `p` as pointing to an `uint16_t`, de-references this pointer, which gives a 16bit value, converts this from network- to host-byte-order and finally masks out out everything but the lowest 4 bit.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification :). After using `unsigned int protocol_version = *((uint16_t *) p);` as you suggested, i get the `protocol_version` as `69` for packets that are IPv4.

Comment: Thanks again for bearing with this question.. now the protocol version is i get is 5..

Comment: Ok fixed it finally, the 4 msb from the first byte carry the version.

Comment: As per the updated answer the protocol version now i get is 5 which represents ST.. I tested with wireshark, and according to that it should be getting 4.

Comment: Yes sir, now i changed it :)..Thank you very much sir! thanks a bunch!! :) a big headache is off my shoulders thanks to you